# How to display a gigantic data grid without breaking flexbox layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tablelayout

I have this requirement where the users want to see huge gigantic tables that require loss of horizontal scrolling. The problem is the data table is loaded AFTER the header/content/footer layout (flexbox) has already been set. When it does load, it just ends up loading outside of everything (as seen in the screenshot below) and looks broken.

It looks fine until you scroll all the way to the right, then you can see that the table extends past the header and footer.

[image: table breaks layout]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  height:100vh; 
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.row-wrapper{ 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
nav {
    flex: 0 0 30px;
 }
main{
    margin-left:5px;
    flex:1
}
header {
   background: blue;
   color: white; 
}
footer {
   background: black;
   color: white;
}
header, footer{
  display: block;
  flex:none;
}
```

```html
<div class ="container">
    <header>I AM HEADER</header>
    <div class="row-wrapper">
        <nav>Side links</nav>
        <main>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                 <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                         <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                 <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                           <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                 <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson</td> 
                <td>94</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Eve</td>
                <td>Jackson</td> 
                <td>94</td>
                <td>50</td>
                         <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                 <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                           <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
                 <td>Jill</td>
                <td>Smith</td> 
                <td>50</td>
                <td>50</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </main>
    </div>
    <footer>I AM FOOTER </footer>
</div>
```

How can I get the flexbox layout to readjust to this new gigantic table?

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gz193L5h/1/)

Comment: Flexbox does adapt to new content (in fact, CSS does that in general). Which means that you have some other problem that prevents the table from being counted. My first guess would be `display: absolute;` or something similar to that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I just added a jsfiddle which more clearly demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by setting `width:auto` and `position:absolute` in the `<div class="container">`.